# how to change image in razor page in asp.net core 2

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have some logic in C#, that controls which image I should show on a webpage.

basically I want to update the image, when a button is pushed, but I want to do it in the controller of a razor page. And not I javascript or html, where it is fairly simple.

I am thinking somehow along the lines of:
// the controller

```
 public class APageController {
    ...
    public IActionResult AButtonPushed() {
       bool yes;
       ...
       // some logic that changes yes 
       ...
       aPageModel.ImagePath = yes               // how do I access the 
                         ? "\images\true.jpg"   // razor view class from 
                         : "\images\ohNooo.jpg" // controller
      return RedirectToPage("/aPage");
      }
    ... 
 }
```

// the razor page model

```
  public class aPageModel : PageModel {
    ... 
    public string ImagePath {get;set;}
    ... 
 }
```

// and the razor page html

```
   ...
   < img src="@Model.ImagePath"/>
   ...
```

or it maybe I should use some helper tag, to force the page to react to the change of imagePath in the PageModel.

Comment: This is impossible, you can't change the dom without using Javascript. Once the image is loaded, the only way to change it is using client side code or by reloading the webpage.

Comment: hmm the server logic controls the image to be shown, so I need to reload the page?

Comment: have your click button call the controller to change the image, it will reload the page. You can toggle your bool or you can have send the current image value then do a logic to your controller to change the image.